Why are my layers not showing up in MapContent?
I'm entering the last few hours to defend my thesis (for college). I have written everything, but a huge problem is happening, why are the Layers not displayed when I add them to the MapContent from the drawLine method in the CursorTool classes, that's all for this.
P.S. layers are created, and features with the correct coordinate system.

   package priprema;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spatialdatatypes.Point;
import com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.LineString;
import com.mongodb.client.model.geojson.Polygon;
import org.geotools.api.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.geotools.api.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.geotools.api.style.Style;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.util.NullProgressListener;
import org.geotools.feature.AttributeTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.map.MapViewport;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.event.MapMouseEvent;
import org.geotools.swing.tool.CursorTool;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Envelope;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LinearRing;
import org.locationtech.jts.index.SpatialIndex;
import org.locationtech.jts.index.strtree.STRtree;
import org.locationtech.jts.linearref.LocationIndexedLine;

import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Map{

 private final MapContent map;
 private final JMapFrame mapFrame;
 private final JButton btn, btn2, btn3;
 private Map.DigitilizeMap digitizerline;
 private Map.DigitilizeMapPoint digitizerlinepoint;
 private DigitilizeMapPolygon digitizerlinepolygon;
 public Map() {

   this.map = new MapContent();
   var r = new MapViewport();
   r.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
   this.map.setViewport(r);
   this.mapFrame = new JMapFrame(map);
   this.btn3 = new JButton("poligon");
   this.btn2 = new JButton("point");
   this.btn = new JButton("line");

   mapFrame.enableToolBar(true);
   this.mapFrame.enableLayerTable(true);
   this.mapFrame.enableStatusBar(true);

   JToolBar toolBar = mapFrame.getToolBar();
   toolBar.addSeparator();
   this.digitizerlinepolygon = new Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon();
   this.digitizerline = new Map.DigitilizeMap();
   this.digitizerlinepoint = new Map.DigitilizeMapPoint();
   btn3.addActionListener(p -> {
     this.mapFrame.getMapPane().setCursorTool(digitizerlinepolygon);

   });
   btn2.addActionListener(w -> {
     this.mapFrame.getMapPane().setCursorTool(digitizerlinepoint);
   });
   btn.addActionListener(e -> {
     this.mapFrame.getMapPane().setCursorTool(digitizerline);
   });
   toolBar.add(btn3);
   toolBar.add(btn2);
   toolBar.add(btn);

   toolBar.addSeparator();
   // mapFrame.add(toolBar);

   mapFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 500);
   mapFrame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public class DigitilizeMap extends CursorTool {
   private static final SimpleFeatureType type;
   private static final GeometryFactory geo;
   private static final SimpleFeatureBuilder builder;
   private static final Style style;


   static {

     var b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
     b.setName("Linije");
     b.crs(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
     geo = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
     b.add("Point", Point.class);
     AttributeTypeBuilder patb = new AttributeTypeBuilder();
     patb.setNillable(true);
     patb.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
     patb.setBinding(Point.class);
     patb.setName("tacke");

     var Ptype = patb.buildGeometryType();
     patb.buildDescriptor("Point", Ptype);
     b.add("line", Line.class);
     AttributeTypeBuilder latb = new AttributeTypeBuilder();
     latb.setNillable(true);
     latb.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
     latb.setBinding(LineString.class);
     latb.setName("linije");
     var Ltype = latb.buildGeometryType();
     latb.buildDescriptor("line", Ltype);
     type = b.buildFeatureType();
     builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
     style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 10);
     System.out.println("Postavio sam svojstva za crtanje.");
   }

   private final ArrayList<SimpleFeature> lastKnownFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<Coordinate> tempCoord = new ArrayList<>();
   private double lastX, lastY;
   private boolean frst = true;
   private FeatureLayer tempLayer;


   @Override
   public void onMouseDragged(MapMouseEvent e) {
     var graph = ((JComponent) this.getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();

     System.out.println("Pomjerio si");
     List<Coordinate> HelloNeightborPoint = new ArrayList<>();
     System.out.println("1");
     SpatialIndex indexing = new STRtree();
     System.out.println("2");
     var collection = DataUtilities.collection(this.lastKnownFeatures);
     System.out.println("3");
     try {
       collection.accepts((f) -> {
         SimpleFeature simpleFeature = (SimpleFeature) f;
         System.out.println("4");

         Geometry geom = (Geometry) simpleFeature.getAttribute("line");
         System.out.println("ovo je da li ce biti anomajlija ?" + geom.isValid());
         System.out.println("5");
         if (geom != null) {

           Envelope env = geom.getEnvelopeInternal();
           System.out.println("6");
           if (env != null) {
             indexing.insert(env, new LocationIndexedLine(geom));
             System.out.println("7");
           }
         }
       }, new NullProgressListener());
     } catch (IOException e1) {
       System.out.println("null pointer");
     }

       System.out.println("8");
       ReferencedEnvelope bound = collection.getBounds();

       /*
        * podesi parametre grube pretrage
        */ System.out.println("9");
       double EPSILON_OKOLINA = bound.getSpan(0);// broj dimenzija koje moze da ima
                                                             // envelope
                                                 // (ovojnica) sa obzirom na to je li 2d,3d....

       System.out.println("10");
       double frame = 5000;
       double poc = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println("11");
       while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - poc) < 500) {
         // dakle ili prostorno ili vrmensko ogranicenje

         // dodjela false envelopa tj. lazne "zamisljenje" ovojnice, kao nekog prostora kojeg bi
         // tacka htjela imati
         // ovo nece utecati na nasu tacku u temp, ok
         // tacka sama po sebi, je osnovni podatak, potreban za neku geometriju kako bi se ona
         // robusno definisala, a ne nesta sto ce biti i dovoljno, za sta se koriste ovojnice (npr
         // plast sfere je ovojnica, tacka je
         // centar sfere i eventualno jos na sferi
         // Tacki netreba nikakva dodatna zamisljena ovojnica pa je ja dodeljujem
         System.out.println("12");
         var ja = new Coordinate(e.getWorldPos().getX(), e.getWorldPos().getY());
         Envelope justImagine = new Envelope(ja);
         justImagine.expandBy(EPSILON_OKOLINA);// bira koja je veca ovojnica;

         // sve je spremno , idemo

         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         List<LocationIndexedLine> linex = indexing.query(justImagine);// dakle kljuceve pretrazi,
                                                                       // da one koji su ne equal,
                                                                       // već unutar equal prema
                                                                       // nekom svosjtvu envelope
         System.out.println("13");
         // POJAM MATEMATIKE: aksiom neprekidnosti je ovdje odigrao svoje
         double lucna_preciznost = 10E-6;
         final var APROKSIM = EPSILON_OKOLINA + lucna_preciznost;
         if (linex != null & !linex.isEmpty()) {
           System.out.println("imam linija");
           for (var l : linex) {
             var vektor = l.project(ja);
             var maybe = l.extractPoint(vektor);
             if (maybe != null) {
               // dakle nije toliko retka linija
               double trueDist = maybe.distance(ja);

               if (trueDist <= APROKSIM) {

                 HelloNeightborPoint.add(maybe);
                 System.out.println("dodao bar jedan");
                 EPSILON_OKOLINA = trueDist;
               }


             }

           } ;

         }


       }



     System.out.println("15");

     System.out.println("problem u nizu");
     System.out.println(HelloNeightborPoint.isEmpty());
     for (var p : HelloNeightborPoint) {
       System.out.println(p);
       System.out.println("ipak nije");
       graph.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
       graph.fillRect((int) p.getX() - 3, (int) p.getY() - 3, 6, 6);

     }


   }

   @Override
   public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent e) {// problem 1. sto mora non stat, aaaaamovic
     System.out.println("cuem");
     Graphics graphics =
         ((JComponent) Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();



     if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {// double click

       this.drawLine(tempCoord);
         this.frst = true;

     } else {
         var pos = e.getWorldPos();
         System.out.println(pos);
         this.tempCoord.add(new Coordinate(pos.getX(), pos.getY()));
         System.out.println(tempCoord);
         // ovo je bilo glavno
         if (!this.frst) {

           graphics.drawLine((int) this.lastX, (int) this.lastY, e.getX(), e.getY());// stupid temp
                                                                                     // line
           this.lastX = e.getX();
           this.lastY = e.getY();



         } else {
           this.frst = false;
           this.lastX = e.getX();
           this.lastY = e.getY();

         }

       }
       graphics.setColor(Color.red);
       graphics.fillRect(e.getX() - 3, e.getY() - 3, 6, 6);


       }

   @Override
   public void onMouseExited(MapMouseEvent e) {
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().removeMouseListener(this);
   }

   private void drawLine(List<Coordinate> tempCoord) {


     Coordinate[] string = new Coordinate[this.tempCoord.size()];
     if (tempCoord.size() == 1) {
       var point = geo.createPoint(tempCoord.get(0));
       System.out.println(point);
       builder.add(point);
       builder.add(null);
     } else {
       for (int i = 0; i < this.tempCoord.size(); i++) {
       string[i] = this.tempCoord.get(i);
         System.out.println(tempCoord.get(i));
       }
       var line = Map.DigitilizeMap.geo.createLineString(string);
     System.out.println(line);
       builder.add(null);
     Map.DigitilizeMap.builder.add(line);
     }
     var feature =
         DigitilizeMap.builder
             .buildFeature(null);
     this.lastKnownFeatures.add(feature);
     var FeatureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(this.lastKnownFeatures);
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().removeLayer(tempLayer);
     this.tempLayer = new FeatureLayer(FeatureCollection, Map.DigitilizeMap.style);
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().addLayer(tempLayer);
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().layers().forEach(e -> e.setVisible(true));


     this.tempCoord = new ArrayList<>();// da ne dobijemo gomilu svega

   }

 }

 public class DigitilizeMapPoint extends CursorTool {
   private static final SimpleFeatureType type;
   private static final GeometryFactory geo;
   private static final SimpleFeatureBuilder builder;
   private static final Style style;


   static {

     var r = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
     r.setName("Tacke");
     r.crs(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
     geo = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
     r.add("Point", Point.class);
     type = r.buildFeatureType();
     builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
     style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 20);
     System.out.println("Postavio sam svojstva za crtanje.");
   }

   private final ArrayList<SimpleFeature> lastKnownFeatures = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<Coordinate> tempCoord = new ArrayList<>();


   private FeatureLayer tempLayer;


   @Override
   public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent e) {// problem 1. sto mora non stat, aaaaamovic
     System.out.println("work");
     Graphics graphics =
         ((JComponent) Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();


     if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {// double click

       this.drawLine(tempCoord);


     } else {
       var pos = e.getWorldPos();
       System.out.println(pos);
       this.tempCoord.add(new Coordinate(pos.getX(), pos.getY()));
       System.out.println(tempCoord);
       // ovo je bilo glavno


     }
     graphics.setColor(Color.red);
     graphics.fillRect(e.getX() - 3, e.getY() - 3, 6, 6);

   }

   @Override
   public void onMouseExited(MapMouseEvent e) {
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().removeMouseListener(this);
   }

   private void drawLine(List<Coordinate> tempCoord) {


     for (Coordinate c : tempCoord) {
       var point = geo.createPoint(c);
       System.out.println(point);
       builder.set(0, point);
       var feature = DigitilizeMapPoint.builder.buildFeature(null);
       this.lastKnownFeatures.add(feature);
     }


     var FeatureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(this.lastKnownFeatures);

     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().removeLayer(tempLayer);
     this.tempLayer = new FeatureLayer(FeatureCollection, Map.DigitilizeMapPoint.style);
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().addLayer(tempLayer);


     this.tempCoord = new ArrayList<>();// da ne dobijemo gomilu svega

   }

 }

 public class DigitilizeMapPolygon extends CursorTool {

   private static SimpleFeatureType type;
   private static SimpleFeatureBuilder builder;
   private static GeometryFactory ring;
   private static final Style style = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.green, Color.gray, 10);
   static {
     SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
     b.setName("Poligon");
     b.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
     b.add("poligon", Polygon.class);
     DigitilizeMapPolygon.type = b.buildFeatureType();
     DigitilizeMapPolygon.builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
     DigitilizeMapPolygon.ring = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

   }


   private final List<SimpleFeature> poly = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<LinearRing> rings = new ArrayList<>();
   private double lastX, lastY;
   private boolean frst = true;
   private boolean out = true;
   private FeatureLayer layer;

   // osnovna ideja je da se izbjegne anomajlija, viseca linija, koja nema povrsinu, dakle sve sto
   // je potrebno,
   // na kraju sto korisnik iscrta komad linija da ja uzmem i zatvorim to u poligon (hocu reci ne
   // on)

   @Override
   public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent e) {// problem 1. sto mora non stat, aaaaamovic

     Graphics graphics =
         ((JComponent) Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();


     if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {// double click
       graphics.drawLine((int) this.lastX, (int) this.lastY, (int) this.coords.get(0).getX(),
           (int) this.coords.get(0).getY());// stupid temp
       this.drawLine(this.coords);
       this.frst = true;




     } else {
       var pos = e.getWorldPos();

       System.out.println(pos);
       this.coords.add(new Coordinate(pos.getX(), pos.getY()));
       System.out.println(coords);
       // ovo je bilo glavno
       if (!this.frst) {

         graphics.drawLine((int) this.lastX, (int) this.lastY, e.getX(), e.getY());// stupid temp
                                                                                   // line
         this.lastX = e.getX();
         this.lastY = e.getY();


       } else {
         this.frst = false;
         this.lastX = e.getX();
         this.lastY = e.getY();

       }

     }
     graphics.setColor(Color.red);
     graphics.fillRect(e.getX() - 3, e.getY() - 3, 6, 6);


   }

   @Override
   public void onMouseExited(MapMouseEvent e) {
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().removeMouseListener(this);
   }

   private void drawLine(List<Coordinate> tempCoord) {
     Coordinate[] string = new Coordinate[tempCoord.size() + 1];

     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < tempCoord.size(); i++) {
       string[i] = tempCoord.get(i);
       System.out.println(tempCoord.get(i));
     }
     string[i] = tempCoord.get(0);// zatvara poligon
     var ring = Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.ring.createLinearRing(string);
     this.rings.add(ring);


     if (this.out) {
       this.out = false;
       this.coords = new ArrayList<>();
     } else {

       LinearRing[] rings = new LinearRing[this.rings.size() - 1];
       for (int j = this.rings.size() - 1, r = 0; j > 0; j--, r++) {
         rings[r] = this.rings.get(j);
       }
       var p = Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.ring.createPolygon(this.rings.get(0), rings);

       Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.builder.add(p);

       var feature =
           DigitilizeMapPolygon.builder
               .buildFeature(null);
       this.poly.add(feature);
       var FeatureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(this.poly);
       if (layer != null) {
         Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().removeLayer(this.layer);
       }
       this.layer = new FeatureLayer(FeatureCollection, Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.style);
       Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().addLayer(layer);


       this.out = true;
       this.rings = new ArrayList<>();
       this.coords = new ArrayList<>();
     }
   }
 }
}



It is enough to watch only this part, you don't have to watch everything, because everything is happening here.

 public class DigitilizeMapPolygon extends CursorTool {

   private static SimpleFeatureType type;
   private static SimpleFeatureBuilder builder;
   private static GeometryFactory ring;
   private static final Style style = SLD.createPolygonStyle(Color.green, Color.gray, 10);
   static {
     SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
     b.setName("Poligon");
     b.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
     b.add("poligon", Polygon.class);
     DigitilizeMapPolygon.type = b.buildFeatureType();
     DigitilizeMapPolygon.builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(type);
     DigitilizeMapPolygon.ring = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

   }


   private final List<SimpleFeature> poly = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<Coordinate> coords = new ArrayList<>();
   private List<LinearRing> rings = new ArrayList<>();
   private double lastX, lastY;
   private boolean frst = true;
   private boolean out = true;
   private FeatureLayer layer;

   // osnovna ideja je da se izbjegne anomajlija, viseca linija, koja nema povrsinu, dakle sve sto
   // je potrebno,
   // na kraju sto korisnik iscrta komad linija da ja uzmem i zatvorim to u poligon (hocu reci ne
   // on)

   @Override
   public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent e) {// problem 1. sto mora non stat, aaaaamovic

     Graphics graphics =
         ((JComponent) Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane()).getGraphics().create();


     if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {// double click
       graphics.drawLine((int) this.lastX, (int) this.lastY, (int) this.coords.get(0).getX(),
           (int) this.coords.get(0).getY());// stupid temp
       this.drawLine(this.coords);
       this.frst = true;




     } else {
       var pos = e.getWorldPos();

       System.out.println(pos);
       this.coords.add(new Coordinate(pos.getX(), pos.getY()));
       System.out.println(coords);
       // ovo je bilo glavno
       if (!this.frst) {

         graphics.drawLine((int) this.lastX, (int) this.lastY, e.getX(), e.getY());// stupid temp
                                                                                   // line
         this.lastX = e.getX();
         this.lastY = e.getY();


       } else {
         this.frst = false;
         this.lastX = e.getX();
         this.lastY = e.getY();

       }

     }
     graphics.setColor(Color.red);
     graphics.fillRect(e.getX() - 3, e.getY() - 3, 6, 6);


   }

   @Override
   public void onMouseExited(MapMouseEvent e) {
     Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().removeMouseListener(this);
   }

   private void drawLine(List<Coordinate> tempCoord) {
     Coordinate[] string = new Coordinate[tempCoord.size() + 1];

     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < tempCoord.size(); i++) {
       string[i] = tempCoord.get(i);
       System.out.println(tempCoord.get(i));
     }
     string[i] = tempCoord.get(0);// zatvara poligon
     var ring = Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.ring.createLinearRing(string);
     this.rings.add(ring);


     if (this.out) {
       this.out = false;
       this.coords = new ArrayList<>();
     } else {

       LinearRing[] rings = new LinearRing[this.rings.size() - 1];
       for (int j = this.rings.size() - 1, r = 0; j > 0; j--, r++) {
         rings[r] = this.rings.get(j);
       }
       var p = Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.ring.createPolygon(this.rings.get(0), rings);

       Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.builder.add(p);

       var feature =
           DigitilizeMapPolygon.builder
               .buildFeature(null);
       this.poly.add(feature);
       var FeatureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(this.poly);
       if (layer != null) {
         Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().removeLayer(this.layer);
       }
       this.layer = new FeatureLayer(FeatureCollection, Map.DigitilizeMapPolygon.style);
       Map.this.mapFrame.getMapPane().getMapContent().addLayer(layer);


       this.out = true;
       this.rings = new ArrayList<>();
       this.coords = new ArrayList<>();
     }
   }


I would check your imports, I doubt that you want the Line, point, line string or polygon that you are importing. They should all come from jts

You can either create a new Layer for each feature as I did in the last example or keep an ArrayList of SimpleFeatures and add new features to that, I think you still need to destroy and recreate the Layer each time you add to it, but you might be able to use a dataChanged event to signal to the renderer that it needs to redraw the layer.
